# Why HikariCp creating 2 pools in PCF environment?

Tags: hikaricp, cloud-foundry

I am using 
Spring boot release 2.1.4
Spring Data JPA 2.1.6
HikariCP 3.2.0
Hibernate core-5.3.9

When i use hikari cp properties in application properties file.
It picks up and create Hikari pool while running the application locally.

But the same thing does not apply in Cloud Foundry environment.
There it creates Hikari Pool with default properties, which i do not know where it is taking from.

I tried to override Hikari config using Spring Cloud Connector and giving my hikari pool properties from there.

Now it creates a 2 Hikari Pools: Hikari Pool-1 and Hikari Pool-2 in Cloud Foundry environment. One with my configuration properties and other with default properties.

Could someone explain whats happening and how can I remove the default Hikari pool and just have customized one?